# Defining 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

As per my understanding, we need to define a constant row and a constant column size for a 2d array in c++ unless we are dynamically allocating it.

I tried this piece of code and it worked without any errors.

```
    std::vector<std::string> strs;
    for(int i ; i < 10; ++i)
    {
       strs.push_back("This is a test"+ std::to_string(i)); 
    }
    int length = 0;
    for(int i ; i < 10; ++i)
    {
       if(strs[i].size() > length)
           length = strs[i].size();
    }

    char c[20][length + 1];
    for(int i ; i < 20; ++i)
    {
       memcpy(c[i], "Test", 5);
       cout << c[i] << endl;
    }
```

Could someone please explain how come defining a 2D character array with variable length is possible here?

Thanks
K

Comment: You're not initializing `i` to 0

Answer (score 1):

```
char c[20][length + 1];
```

is not legal C++ if `length` is not a compile time constant. Some compilers, such as g++, allow it as an extension.

Comment: Does that mean it should not be used?

Comment: @user3669040, that is my recommendation.